# How does one add an axis label in Microsoft Office Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

As the title says: How does one add an axis label in Microsoft Office Excel 2010?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the **chart selected** the ribbon changes with **'Chart Tools'** highlighted select the **Layout tab** and it's in the **'labels' group**.

So:

> Chart Tools > Layout > Labels > Axis Titles >
>
> > Primary Horizontal Axis Title > Title Below Axis
>
> *or*
>
> > Primary Vertical Axis Title > Vertical Title

[image: Where the title axis options are in Excel]

Comment: not sure, should be similar, it used to live in the properties dialog of the chart prior to the ribbon over-haul, don't have a mac handy with office 08 on it to check.